# What RDS metrics components FreeableMemory of Cloudwatch Logs?

Tags: amazon-rds, grafana

I want to converting FreeableMemory value to percentage in Grafana. The ways i've through is using filter of Cloudwatch Logs, but for RDSOSMetrics Log Group is many memory field such as `memory.free`, `memory.inactive`, `memory.cached`, etc. Which memory field so that the value of FreeableMemory and Cloudwatch Logs memory field is the same ? Or any other way ?

I've using filter of cloudwatch logs to calculate value to percentage, but i don't know memory field of CW Logs to same value of FreeableMemory.